# Expect send timeout when buffer is big from PHP

Tags: php, expect

This is a part of my Expect script. I run it from a PHP page!

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f
set timeout 10
set olt [lindex $argv 1]
exp_send "show gpon onu baseinfo $olt\r"
expect {
   "*Error*" { send_user "\nInterface Invalida\n"; exit 1 }
   "#"
}
puts "$expect_out(buffer)"
```

When 'show' returns a few lines, the code works fine. But when it returns more than 20 lines, I got this message:

```
can't read "expect_out(buffer)": no such variable
  while executing puts "$expect_out(buffer)
```

This message only appeas when I run from my website in php, like above:

```
 $result = exec("./cmd $olt 2>&1", $output, $return_var );
```

cmd is the script that contains the expect code above.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Running the expect script from command line works fine for big show results.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solutions... hours and hours searching....

```
set NewLineChar "\r"
exp_send "show gpon onu baseinfo $olt\r"
expect {
  $NewLineChar { append saida $expect_out(buffer); exp_continue }
  "*Error*" { send_user "\nInterface Invalida\n"; exit 1 }
  "#"
}
```

:)